# How to fix ':app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses' error in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin

How can I fix this logcat error in flutter when i added local_auth: ^2.1.2 to my project

```
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckDuplicatesRunnable
   > Duplicate class androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelLazy found in modules jetified-lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx-2.3.1-runtime (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.3.1) and lifecycle-viewmodel-2.5.1-runtime (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:2.5.1)
     Duplicate class androidx.lifecycle.ViewTreeViewModelKt found in modules jetified-lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx-2.3.1-runtime (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.3.1) and lifecycle-viewmodel-2.5.1-runtime (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:2.5.1)
```

Here is the kotlin plugin added by default in the build gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"
```

So i can,t really tell where the error is coming from i have tried to clean, rebuild the project and also invalidate and restart andriod studio but the error still persists. Any advice will be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: @MansoorMalik The solution on the shared link works thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to gradle.properties(project properties)
2. Add

   android.enableJetifier=true
3. And also most of time `android.useAndroidX=true` is present.Check your `gradle.properties(Project Properties)` and if it does not exist then add
   `android.useAndroidX=true`

Comment: this is my gradle.properties(project properties) `org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536M
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
`